# Will MySQL allow no primary key if the table is linked with another table containing a MatchID with two Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql, database, primary-key, database-normalization, 3nf

I have a database of 5 tables. Some contain the same columns as others, does tying these tables to another table which has the primary keys of other tables meet 3rd normalisation. (This is outlined more clearly below)

I have a table of customers, with their names and phone numbers as well as requirements they want in their car etc. The primary key is CustomerID.

I then match a customer with a car which matches their requirements. I have a table with Match ID (Primary key) and CustomerID and CarID (As foreign keys.)

By doing this, can I then make a table off Match ID which can be given to the receptionist so that they can contact the customer. In this table I would need to include the customer name and phone number. However, does this break 3rd normal form as Phone number is now both in CustomerID and the new table.

Comment: How are you stuck determining this? DB normalization has nothing to do with FKs per se. Normalization applies to 1 table. So it's really not clear what you are trying to ask about 3NF & your design. You don't relate your design to normalization. [ask] [Help] PS Q&A re basics of DB NFs & re redundancy across tables are faqs. But one must write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question/problem/goal to (re)search reasonably.

Answer (score -1):

The last table you describe doesn't necessarily break any normal form, because the customer's phone number can change in the future. You may want to preserve the phone number in another table so there is a record of what phone number was contacted on that date.

Compare with a database of products. The product table has prices. Then you record customer purchases, with a copy of the price they paid on the date they made the purchase. That's okay because you need a record of what was paid in each case. A customer may buy the product during a sale, or they got a senior discount, or a bulk discount, or the price may change a month after they bought the item, etc. The price they paid is not necessarily the current price recorded in the products table. Therefore it does not violate 3NF.

Comment: I thought that tables without a primary key were against 3NF, is this incorrect? Thank you for the answer as well.

Comment: Why would it not have a primary key, if it's related to the match table, just copy the primary key. Note that primary key != auto-increment.

Comment: As the primary key MatchID would then become the foreign key in the new table.

Comment: A foreign key can also be a primary key.